# The optimal way to find multiple needle in string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search

I`m designing **a parser in java** which finds the name of stock item on news article.

The article`s length is between 500 and 2000 words. and the number of stock items is almost 3000.

I think that this is finding multiple needles in string problem. and I want to know the best algorithm or java library to solve this problem.

I assume that **suffix array** can be a good solution.

Please let me know if you know about the algorithm or some hints.

Thank you.

Comment: Suffix array should be good for large data, but I'm not sure your case is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suffix is a good choice when all strings are static, that is to say you should know the article as well as names of items in advance and they won't change. When articles are not static or there maybe many articles to process, [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) will be a good choice. You can build a Trie based on the names of stock items, then enumerate each position within the article. It cost O(Len(article) * average length of items name), given your input size, it should be efficient enough.

Also, you can use [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm to avoid enumerate each position within the article, and it only costs O(length of article) to find all stock items within the article.

Comment: I found the library, [Aho-Corasick](https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick) I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to find substrings within a longer text. In C# you would simply use methods like Substring. Don't know if they exist in java. Otherwise I would pick the [Boyer–Moore–Horspool algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) to search for substrings and get their position within a given text.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String Tokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) then loop and compare all tokens produced.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems possible to split the input in tokens, the words, and then perform a lookup in a very limited dictionary, the stock items. 
If you do the lookup using hashing, you will have the cost of computing the hash for the words + the hashing itself. Assuming a perfect hash function, this is O(n) where n is the chars in the article.

so (simplified)

```
  Set<String> items...

  String article = getArticle();

  Set<String> found = new HashSet<String>();

 for(String word : article.split(" ")) 
    if(items.contains(word)) 
       found.add(word)
```